# Use case of transaction in Spring AMQP

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

I am trying to understand Spring AMQP. I can't get my head aroud the [transaction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#transactions).

What is the use case of transaction? Is it similar to JTA? Why would someone rollback a `Message`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the documentation about transaction semantics](https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html#tx).

No, it's not "similar to JTA" it applies only to RabbitMQ itself - it can't participate in a global transaction.

One use case:

- publish multiple records and one fails - then all are rolled back

i.e. all published records are secured in the broker, or none are.